# SSRS reports adds Blank columns after exporting it into excel

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, msbi

I have created the SSRS report and it's working fine in preview mode but after exporting the report into excel it adds blank columns.

Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the XML definition for the report please to help isolate the problem as there could be a number of reasons for that happening?

Comment: It might be happening because you have textboxes outside of the tablix that are not lining up.

Comment: A picture of your report in Design and Preview would help us help you out. You can post to imgur.com and paste the link in your question since you don't have enough rep yet to do inline pics.